# lower firestore query reads when searching substring in documents

Tags: java, android, performance, google-cloud-firestore

I have a `firestore` collection with the following structure:

[image]

In one of my activities, I have a search field where a user types and I offer some results in a `recyclerView`.

Now, in order to offer results for the users, I query my collection and I do it by using the following code:

```
atv_Search.addTextChangedListener( new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


        if (s.toString().trim().length() > 0) {

            String[] words = s.toString().trim().split( "\\s+" );
            for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                String Word = words[i];
                words[i] = Word.substring( 0, 1 ).toUpperCase() + Word.substring( 1 );
            }
            s = TextUtils.join( " ", words );

            db.collection( "Books" )
                    .whereArrayContains( "BookTitleArray", s.toString() ).limit( 20 ).get()
                    .addOnCompleteListener( task -> {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                List<String> nameWords = (List<String>) document.get( "BookTitleArray" );
                                String name = TextUtils.join( " ", nameWords );
                                autoBookNames.add( name );
                            }
                        }
                    } );

            db.collection( "Books" )
                    .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo( "BookTitle", s.toString() ).whereLessThanOrEqualTo( "BookTitle", s.toString() + "\uF7FF" ).limit( 20 ).get()
                    .addOnCompleteListener( task -> {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                String name = document.getString( "BookTitle" );
                                autoBookNames.add( name );
                            }
                        }
                    } );
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        new CountDownTimer( 1000, 500 ) {
            public void onFinish() {
                Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<>( autoBookNames );
                autoBookNames.clear();
                autoBookNames.addAll( set );

                adapter = new AutoCompleteAdapter( getApplicationContext(), R.layout.item_auto_search, R.id.item_drop, autoBookNames, false );
                atv_Search.setAdapter( adapter );
                if (!autoBookNames.isEmpty() && notSelected) {
                    atv_Search.showDropDown();
                }
            }

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            }
        }.start();

    }
} );
```

Now, the code works fine but the performances are not what I'm looking for.

By using this code, every single letter the user types, I perform 40 reads from the database (which eventually leads to tons of reads):

1. To looks if the string has the substring by using the 2nd query I use 20 reads.
2. By checking if the array contains a word I use another 20 reads.

I can of course remove the limit(20) but then I might get even bigger problems since I have thousands of documents in the collection.

Is there any smarter way to do it? Any way I can improve it so it won't query 40 reads every letter?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking for performance I would recommend going through [Best Practices](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices) where asynchronous calls and specific key indexing is suggested and [Database Optimization](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices) where it is explained how database design and efficient data structures can make a difference

But more overall check out how to reduce reads in [this article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-drastically-reduce-the-number-of-reads-when-no-documents-are-changed-in-firestore-8760e2f25e9e). There are multiple options that could better fit your business logic such as reading from cache or pagination.

Happy coding!